# How can I fix "Service provider invocation failure" error?

Tags: sabre

I am sending a request to GetReservation in order to retrieve itinerary. I imported WSDL from legacy from this url: http://files.developer.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/pnrservices/GetReservation_1.19.0.wsdl. However I keep receiving exception 'Service provider invocation failure'. I added message header and service value 'GetReservationRQ'.

Comment: It turned out I missed to add version info 1.19.0 to GetReservationRQ

Comment: Future recommendation, capture the complete error response, because the _invocation failure_ is the generic part, but there's more info returned. Another recommendation, post the complete request... with the information you shared is IMPOSSIBLE to help ;)